# kubernetes pod returning failed status when webdriverIO test fails

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, minikube, webdriver-io

we have been using kubernetes pods to run our webdriverio test case scenarios. for the failed test case scenarios, the kubernetes pods return a failed status. is there any way to handle kubernetes pods such that even if a test case fails the corresponding pod status should not end up in a failed status.

Comment: catch error in your application and exit with 0